# String in for loop Python

Tags: python, for-loop, data-manipulation

I want a string column of location values (for example Amsterdam, London, Paris) included in my dataset that already has 2 columns with only integer values. I don't know how to include it with a for loop.

**My code looks like this:**

```
    with open(output_file_path, 'w') as csvfile: 
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        csv_writer.writerow(['timestamp', 'id', 'integercolumn1', 'integercolumn2'])

        for i in range(100):
            csv_writer.writerow([timestamp, 'demo-{}'.format(i), random.randint(0, 75), random.randint(4, 10), ])
```

**The table/dataset looks now like this:**

```
timestamp | ID | integercolumn1 | integercolumn2 | 
2020-1    | 1  | 32             | 25             |
2020-1    | 2  | 45             | 14             |
```

**But I want something like this. Thus random location also included**

```
timestamp | ID | integercolumn1 | integercolumn2 | location
2020-1    | 1  | 32             | 25             | London
2020-1    | 2  | 45             | 14             | Paris
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Answer (score 1):

can you have a list of locations and randomly select from the list like below.Is this what you looking for?

```py
location = ['Paris','London']

with open('test', 'w') as csvfile: 
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        csv_writer.writerow(['timestamp', 'id', 'integercolumn1', 'integercolumn2','location'])
for i in range(10):
    csv_writer.writerow(['demo-{}'.format(i), random.randint(0, 75), 
    random.randint(4, 10), location[random.randint(0, 1)]])
```